# Loop over Delta versions

Tags: databricks-sql

Let's say I have a table 'product'. I want to execute a query to get this table row count over the time using the Delta versions of this table.

I can definitely declare a CTE using the @vX convention (and then joining this CTE on my DESCRIBE HISTORY product to get my final result), but I have too many version right now and I'm looking for something more dynamic.

Is this possible in pure Databricks SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided code will concurrently execute the `count` operation, obtaining counts for each version from the `delta` table.

```
val table = "bronze_db.source"

val versions = spark
  .sql(s"SELECT version FROM (DESCRIBE HISTORY ${table}) T")
  .distinct
  .as[Long]  
  .collect
  .toSeq
```

```
import scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool

val numThreads = 20 // Number of threads to execute query in parallel.
val versionsPar = versions.par

val taskSupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(numThreads))
versionsPar.tasksupport = taskSupport
```

```
display(
  versionsPar
    .map(version =>
      (
        version,
        spark
          .sql(s""" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${table}@v${version} """)
          .as[Long]
          .collect
          .headOption
          .getOrElse(0L)
      )
    )
    .toList
    .toDF("version", "count")
    .orderBy($"version".asc)
)
```